# Discord.js. CronJob not working with command handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, discord.js

As said in the title I have a problem when i need to export a schedule made with CronJob. The error I get is:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`

Inside of `Cron.js` I have:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require("fs");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { prefix, token } = require("../config.json");

const cron = require("cron")

const test = new cron.CronJob("00 00 13 * * 5", () =>{
    client.channels.fetch("768752722743918614")
    let testmsg = client.channels.cache.get("768752722743918614")
    testmsg.send("test")
})
module.exports = test
```

Inside of `bot.js`:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require("fs");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { prefix, token } = require("../config.json");

const cron = require("cron")
const test = require("./commands/autocode")

test.start()
```

That schedule works without problems inside `bot.js`, but I don't want to make it untidy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `client.channels.cache.get` returns undefined. I think you could just pass the `client` down to your cron job to use the same client instance. You can return a function that returns the cron job you want to `.start()`:

```js
const cron = require("cron");

const test = (client) => new cron.CronJob("00 00 13 * * 5", () => {
    client.channels.fetch("768752722743918614");
    let testmsg = client.channels.cache.get("768752722743918614");
    testmsg.send("test");
})
module.exports = test;
```

`bot.js`

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require("fs");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { prefix, token } = require("../config.json");

const cron = require("cron");
const test = require("./commands/autocode")(client);

test.start();
```